# How config nginx to prevent attack core file wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

My wordpress site had redirect hack. Some files affected as: index.php, wp-config.php, wp-blog-header.php, and uploaded .ico file to source code
How to block the specialadves WordPress Redirect Hack

Comment: The attack probably wasn't from nginx surface, but from some wo vulnerability or some plugin vulnerability. Keep your wp and plugins up to date, use higher php versions, also if you're running on a shared server check you're using correct chmod permissions for your files. NEVER EVER use 777

Comment: what are the plugins you are using?. js files also affected?

Comment: Yes, .js file in wp-included affected

Comment: You can see more about this malware in this link: https://blog.sucuri.net/2022/02/how-to-fix-the-specialadves-wordpress-redirect-hack.html